# timeout with collected data

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, polling

I am calling api recursively with the help of rxjs expand operator, here i get data from server, whenever i get status: false, stop recursion and collect all data with the help of array.

Here it is working fine but what if i never get status: false so this will continuously loop http requests which is not good. I want to set Timeout for http request but this will throw error after specified time but i need data until get timeout. any idea?

example reference:

```
let counterOfItemsFetched = 0;
function api() {
    // console.log('counterOfItemsFetched', counterOfItemsFetched)
    return counterOfItemsFetched < 1000 ? 100 : 1;
}

function apiAsynCall() {
    return Observable.of(api()).delay(1000);
}

Observable.of(0).pipe(
    expand(() => apiAsynCall().pipe(tap(itemsFetched => counterOfItemsFetched = counterOfItemsFetched + itemsFetched))),
    filter(counter => counter > 0),
    tap(() => console.log(counterOfItemsFetched)),
    takeWhile(counter => counter ===  100),
)
.subscribe(
    null,
    null,
    () => console.log('counter value at the end', counterOfItemsFetched)
)
```

Comment: So you want to timeout the whole chain or just each http request?

Comment: i want to timeout http request which we are doing recursively, i use toArray operator to collect all emit data each time

Comment: You can use `timeout()` chained `catchError(() => EMPTY)` to suppress the error.

Comment: yes i can use but i need data until polling with timeout, we have timeoutwith operator but in this case i don't know how to pass data to timeoutWith

Comment: What do you mean by "i need data until polling with timeout" when you want to be able to timeout each request?

Comment: i mean, i use polling to server, each time i get some data but this get will stop after 15 seconds so i should make timeout, collect all data which receive from server during polling. sorry i need to apply timeout to whole chain.

Comment: I should stop polling after 15 seconds, if there is any data during polling, pass it to timeout

Comment: i use ```takeUntil(timer(10000).pipe(tap(() => logger.info(`maximum polling timeout: 10000 reached`))))``` this will map all data after finish timeout